# how to use two network interface in linux

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

I have two or more network interface at the same time and want to use each network for sending special requests over it.(i want to know how to do that with iptables and other like this )

> **for example :**
>   I want to see a video by "network-1" and other requests I want to send with "network-2"

```
ifconfig
```

output:

```
enx0c5b8f279a64: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.8.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.8.255
    inet6 fe80::af19:e5c2:350e:ad09  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 74  bytes 16183 (16.1 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 122  bytes 16282 (16.2 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 5290686  bytes 3859055101 (3.8 GB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 5290686  bytes 3859055101 (3.8 GB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1400
    inet 81.31.179.204  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 172.17.1.230
    ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
    RX packets 292544  bytes 336720863 (336.7 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 178723  bytes 16928573 (16.9 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::a71b:2220:7e40:1948  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether e4:70:b8:cf:4f:81  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 4691632  bytes 4626078058 (4.6 GB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 4675065  bytes 704065262 (704.0 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and my IP route is

```
ip route show
```

output:

```
default dev ppp0 proto static scope link metric 50 
default via 192.168.8.1 dev enx0c5b8f279a64 proto dhcp metric 20100 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp metric 20600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.1.230 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 src 192.168.1.2 
172.17.1.230 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 81.31.179.204 metric 50 
172.17.1.230 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 proto static metric 600 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2 metric 600 
192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 proto static scope link metric 600 
192.168.8.0/24 dev enx0c5b8f279a64 proto kernel scope link src 
192.168.8.100 metric 100
```

at that time `wlp2s0` and `enx0c5b8f279a64` are my two network interface

I want to send some of my requests  through `enx0c5b8f279a64` (that will be specified by setting browser on a proxy over it) and other requests i want to send through `wlp2s0`.